# How many elements of order $2$ are in the alternating group $A_8$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

So for this question I thought the number of elements of order $2$ in the alternating group $A_8$ would be calculated by doing $\frac{8!}{2^44!}+\frac{8!}{2^22!}=5145$ as for order $2$ it must be from $4$ $2$-cycles and 2 2-cycles however the answer I'm getting is incorrect. Can anyone advise on how to get the answer?

Comment: You are missing the products of two disjoint $2$-cycles.

Comment: The [OEIS sequence A000704](http://oeis.org/A000704) "Number of degree-n even permutations of order dividing 2." is one more than the number of permutations in $A_n$ of order $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second summand should be
$$
\frac{8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5}{2^{2} \cdot 2!} = 210.
$$

And please do not forget to speak of four *disjoint* $2$-cycles and two *disjoint* $2$-cycles.

Comment: Well handled, the teaching part in particular :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using the decomposition of a permutation as a product of disjoint cycles, you have that these cycles have to be disjoint transpositions, and as we're in $A_8$, they have to be the product of an *even* number of transpositions. Explicitly, you should have

- either the product of two disjoint transpositions, which are $\frac12\dbinom 82\dbinom 62$ in number,
- or the product of four disjoint transpositions, which are $\frac1{24}\dbinom 82\dbinom 62\dbinom 42$ in number.

Comment: Allow me, you are overcounting. There are $315$ involutions in $A_{8}$, while your formulas give $420 + 2520 = 2940$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: you're right, the product of transpositions were counted twice in the first case, and $3!$ times in the second, which makes $630$. But I still don't see why one would have to divide by $2$ this last calculation.

Comment: This is best seen by considering the general case of the product of $k$ cycles of length $l$ in $S_n$. You count them as $n (n-1) \cdots (n - k l + 1)/(l^k k!)$.

Comment: Finally, I've got  it. I didn't know this formula (permutation groups are not my domain of activity). Do you have a reference?

Comment: I don't have my books handy, so I cannot give you a book reference right now.

Comment: Found a reference. It's Theorem 1.15(b) in (my edition of) Peter Cameron's Permutation Groups.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll see that as soon as  my university is reopened.